# Adding reading time to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multisite on Wordpress where each site is for one country where the company has offices. All sites follow the same structure, only content changes from one to another.
The international/global website is the **.com** version, and the countries uses directories: **.com/dk/**, **.com/de/** and so on.

I'm working to show before the post content, the tags and estimated reading time.

On `functions.php` I have:

```
function reading_time() {
  $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
  $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
  $readingtime = ceil($word_count / 200);

  $lang = get_country_code();
  $timer['lang'] = $lang;

  if (in_array($lang, array('Global', 'UK', 'US', 'ME'))) {
    $timer = " minutes";
  } elseif (in_array($lang, array('CO', 'CL', 'MX', 'GT', 'CR', 'EC'))) {
    $timer = " minutos";
  } elseif (in_array($lang, array('DE', 'CH'))) {
    $timer = " Minuten";
  } elseif (in_array($lang, array('DK' ))) {
    $timer = " minutter";
  } elseif (in_array($lang, array('BR' ))) {
    $timer = " minutos";
  }

  $totalreadingtime = $readingtime . $timer;

  return $totalreadingtime;
}
```

And on `single.php` I added:

```
<div class="post-new-metas">
    <p class="post-tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
    <p class="post-reading-time"><?php echo reading_time(); ?></p>
</div>
```

I'm having 2 troubles with it:
  1. I want to add before the reading time "**Estimated reading time:**" that can change based on the language of the website.
  2. The tags and reading time works on the international/global website. All other sites give me the message: **You have a critical error on your website.**

How can I change the function to allow this to work?

Comment: 1) Use the built in WP translate functions `__('string here')` or `_e('string here')` The `_e()` echoes the string the other returns the string to use later. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/ 2) What is the error? Check the error logs to see what the actual error is. Without that, we can't really help.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. I don't know much about backend. I was able to make this work.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I was able to make the code work with @desinfor's tip. I added on `single.php` file:

```
<div class="post-new-metas">
    <p class="post-tags"><?php the_tags( $before = '<b>Tags:</b> ' ); ?> |

    <?php
    function reading_time() {
      $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
      $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
      $readingtime = ceil($word_count / 200);

      return $readingtime;
    }

    $readingtimeresult = reading_time();

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span>%s</span><span>%s</span>',
                __( '<b>Estimated reading time:</b> ', 'text_domain' ) . $readingtimeresult,
        __( ' minutes', 'Avada' ),
    );
    echo __( $html );
    ?>
    </p>
</div>
```